# How to not work Android intent-filter host from my domain?

Tags: android, intentfilter, android-app-indexing

```
<intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name" android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http"
                  android:host="mydomain.com"
                  android:pathPrefix="/path" />
</intent-filter>
```

I set android `Manifest` like above for Firebase App-Indexing.
It works well.
But when user visit my domain with internet browser and click something on my content(eg. "mydomain.com/path?key=100"), my app is opened. 
Because I have set like that. It's very annoying.

My intention is I want to lead to my app but not from my website.
User is already in my website. I don't want to disturb them.

How can I prevent opening app only from my website?

Answer (score 0):

From [Android Deep linking](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking), `BROWSABLE` category is

> required in order for the intent filter to be accessible from a web
>   browser. Without it, clicking a link in a browser cannot resolve to
>   your app.

Also for the `DEFAULT` category :

> allows your app to respond to implicit intents. Without this, the activity can be started only if the intent specifies your app component name.

I would suggest removing the `DEFAULT` category from this intent filter as then it won't implicitly lead to your app.